# Is there a way to make a button in a Racket web application call a function defined within the file?

Tags: web-applications, functional-programming, lisp, racket

I would like to know if it's possible to create a button that calls a function such as `(define example (print "Hello"))` when a user clicks a button - *without* using a submit button.

For example:

```
(define status "true")
...
 (span (value ,status))
```

I can obtain the value of *status* which is defined in the Racket file and it will show on my webpage, but are there any ways to implement a button that calls a function such as the one mentioned previously?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you detect key presses on a Racket web application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42473515/how-do-you-detect-key-presses-on-a-racket-web-application)

Comment: I think J.Doe wants to trigger a function at the server and that is possible. The "Key Press" question was how to get something running on the client (if I recall correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `embed/url`.

http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/page.html?q=embed%2Furl#%28form._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fpage..rkt%29._embed%2Furl%29%29

For a larger example see:

http://docs.racket-lang.org/continue/index.html?q=continue#%28part._.Adding_a_.Back_.Button%29